# How do I filter for multiple object properties at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 state objects in react - 1 is my overall data object state, the other is the filter data that is controlled from radio/checkboxes that is changed ie

```
{
  color: "blue"
  shape: "square"
}
```

If the user was to select color: blue, and shape: square how could I filter this to ensure that only results are returned that have these values in their dataset?

My code as follows only works for one object type. It filters correctly for color: blue but when shape: square is selected as well the data is filtered only for square.

```
 function compareState(checkboxData, dataset) {
    let data = ''
    let selectedItems = [];
    console.log(checkboxData)
    if (checkboxData.hasOwnProperty('Compatible_with')) {
      Object.entries(checkboxData).map(check => {
        let key = check[0];
        let val = check[1];
        if (dataset[key][val] !== '') {
          data = dataset['name']
        } else {
          data = false
        }
      })
    }
```

My question I guess is that I am stuck on how to ensure both(all) criteria are met to filter my data? As I am in a loop it cannot be retrieved...

Comment: If you think logically about your question, the answer is within reach: "_ensure both(all) criteria are met_" - That would mean `color` AND `shape`. Said differently, `color==='blue' && shape === 'square'`

Comment: Sorry I don't think I worded the question particuarly well. I understand that much but if I am looping over the data in the `Object.entries(checkboxData) loop` - this conditional - `if (dataset[key][val] !== '')` - cannot be used for multiple items

Comment: And my comment was equally deficient then: It should be clear that if you want to evaluate more than one `property=>checkbox` pairing at a time, you cannot do it by iterating over a single `checkbox` at a time.

Comment: OK - that's fair what would be an appropriate solution for this

Comment: Use `reduce` rather than `map` and track the matches. The single result from the `reduce` could be an array of the _checked_ properties.